# Checking for duplicates with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have some code that looks very similar to this in a create function:

```
if(req.body.test !== undefined)
{
        if(--req.body.test EXISTS IN test (model)--)
        {
            DO STUFF
        }
        else
        {
            DO OTHER STUFF
        }

}
```

I've been brainstorming for a while now, and I can't seem to figure out what code I would need to use to figure out the `--req.body.test EXISTS IN test (model)--` part....I know it can't be as hard as I'm thinking it is.

Any help appreciated....

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can it be something as simple as a `count()`?

`if(db.collection.count({test: "test"}) > 2)`

Comment: This seems like a much better solution...I'll test it out and get back to you! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried a unique index at the MongoDB level and then catch a mongoose uniqueness error?

```
db.models.createIndex({ test: 1 }, { unique: true })
```

Then insert and check for error code `11001`. You can also `findOne` and see if a document comes back.

Comment: Do you have any example code for checking the error code? Sorry, I'm new to mongoose.

Comment: This seems like a very inefficient solution. If this is run on every request it is going to create huge overhead as the database tries and fails to construct this index every time. Something like a count or using the aggregation framework would be much better.

Comment: @ThrowsException unique indexes are extremely efficient, and of course you wouldn't build it on every request only once

Comment: @AJcodez His example is checking for duplicates when an express request comes in. So yes, in his example you would be trying to build it on every request.

Comment: @AJcodez I ended up using ThrowsException's example as it did what I needed w less code....thanks anyway though!